# jstl object not getting paramaters from jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have my bean linked correctly in my JSP page:

```
<jsp:useBean id = "productManager" scope = "session"  class = "Smithd81.InventoryManager">
<jsp:getProperty name = "productManager" property = "productList" />
</jsp:useBean>
```

I can verify it works, because the following line allows me to get its length:

```
Products in List = <%= productManager.getProductList().size() %>
```

The end goal here is to iterate over the objects in the list to display their values, but why is this coming up blank?!

Any potential help is welcome, however, for those of you who will mention that my package name has a capital letter, I've attempted to refactor that and change it twice now, and when I do it breaks the whole project.

In the following block, the first line shows how many items are in the list. The next lines, however, get nothing.

```
<p>It is ${fn:length(productManager.productList)}</p>        
<c:forEach var="p" items="${productManager.productList}">
    <div>
        <form action="inventory" method="POST">
            <label>
                <span>UPC</span>
                <input type="text" name="upc" value="${p.getUpc()}" readonly="readonly"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Short Details</span>
                <input type="text" name="shortDetails" value="${p.getShortDetails()}" />
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Long Details</span>
                <input type="text" name="longDetails" value="${p.getLongDetails()}" />
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Price</span>
                <input type="text" name="price" value="${p.getPrice()}" />
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Stock</span>
                <input type="text" name="stock" value="${p.getStock()}" />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Edit" />
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Delete" />
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Create" />
        </form>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

---

Heres is the full JSP

```
<%--
    Document   : inventory
    Created on : Mar 6, 2016, 3:27:11 PM
    Author     : Barad-Dur
--%>
<%@page import="Smithd81.Product"%>
<jsp:useBean id = "productManager" scope = "session"  class = "Smithd81.InventoryManager">
<jsp:getProperty name = "productManager" property = "productList" />
</jsp:useBean>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3.org/StyleSheets/Core/Oldstyle" type="text/css" />
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Inventory Manager JSP!</h1>
        <hr />
        Products in List = <%= productManager.getProductList().size() %>
        <h2>Products:</h2>
        <c:if test="${empty productManager.productList}">                  
            <p> its empty </p>
        </c:if>

                <c:forEach var="p" items="${productManager.productList}">
                    <div>
                        <form action="inventory" method="POST">
                            <label>
                                <span>UPC</span>
                                <input type="text" name="upc" value="${p.getUpc()}" readonly="readonly"/>
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <span>Short Details</span>
                                <input type="text" name="shortDetails" value="${p.getShortDetails()}" />
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <span>Long Details</span>
                                <input type="text" name="longDetails" value="${p.getLongDetails()}" />
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <span>Price</span>
                                <input type="text" name="price" value="${p.getPrice()}" />
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <span>Stock</span>
                                <input type="text" name="stock" value="${p.getStock()}" />
                            </label>
                            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Edit" />
                            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Delete" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>            

    </body>
</html>
```

By request, here is the code for the InventoryManager bean:

```
/*****************************************************
* Class InventoryManager
* @author: Daniel Smith
* @version 1.0.0
* Date: 2/20/2016
* This class provides the intermediary step for getting 
* Products, lists of products, adding, deleting, or
* updating products in the list.
*****************************************************/
package Smithd81;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import edu.lcc.citp.utility.CollectionFileStorageUtility;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 *
 * @author Barad-Dur
 */
public class InventoryManager {

    public InventoryManager(){

    }
    /**
     * The getProduct method gets a list of products and loops over the list
     * until it finds one with a getUpc() value that matches the string passed
     * to it. Once found, the method returns the object to the calling method.
     *
     * In the event no objects are found, a null Product is returned.
     *
     * @param s UPC to search for.
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */
    public Product getProduct(String s) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        List<Product> list = getProductList();
        //search list for upc (s)
        Product match = null;

        /*
         Search each item in the list. This loop checks each item, comparing the 's'
         parameter to each items returned UPC fom the getUpc() method. When it finds a match
         it returns the Product object, or null if none is found.
         */
        for (Product p : list) {
            if (p.getUpc().equals(s)) {
                return p;
            }
        }
        return match; // returns the matching object, or null.
    }

    /**
     * The getProductList method creates an empty List, then creates a
     * Collection and fills it with the values from the
     * CollectionFileStorageUtility.load method. Assuming no exceptions occur
     * here, it loads the Collection values into the List, and returns it to the
     * calling method.
     *
     * @return The product list, or null in the case of an exception.
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */
public List<Product> getProductList() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    return new ArrayList<>(CollectionFileStorageUtility.load(Product.class));

}

    /**
     * The addProduct method gets a list of products from the getProductList()
     * method. It loops over the list to make sure no Product already exists
     * with the same UPC. If no matching UPC is found, the item is added to the
     * list, and the list is saved using the CollectionFileStorageUtility.save
     * method.
     *
     * @param p the Product object to add to the list.
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */
    public void addProduct(Product p) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        List<Product> list = getProductList();

        boolean containsProductAlready = false;
        for (Product listProduct : list) {
            if (listProduct.getUpc().equals(p.getUpc())) {
                containsProductAlready = true;
                System.out.println("Sorry, an item already exists with that UPC.");
                break; //exit the loop
            }
        }
        if (!containsProductAlready) {
            list.add(p); //adds the product if it wasnt found in the list.
            Collections.sort(list);
            CollectionFileStorageUtility.save(list, Product.class); //saves updated list.
        }

    }

    /**
     * The updateProduct method creates a list of Products using the
     * getProductList() method. It then iterates over them to find an object
     * with a matching UPC. When a match is found, it changes updates the traits
     * wherever they were different than the stored traits, except for when they
     * were blank. CollectionFileStorageUtility.save is then called to save the
     * updated list.
     *
     * This does not allow a user to change a UPC.
     *
     * @param p The product containing updated values.
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */
    public void updateProduct(Product p) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        List<Product> list = getProductList();
        boolean containsProductAlready = false;
        for (Product listProduct : list) {
            if ((listProduct.getUpc().equals(p.getUpc()))) {
                containsProductAlready = true;
                //set new product info here.

                //if new  object Long Details is not blank, update it. on the 
                // current listProduct element.
                if (!(p.getLongDetails().equals(""))) {
                    listProduct.setLongDetails(p.getLongDetails());
                    System.out.println(p.getLongDetails());
                }
                //if new object Short Details is not blank, update it. on the 
                // current listProduct element.
                if (!(p.getShortDetails().equals(""))) {
                    listProduct.setShortDetails(p.getShortDetails());
                }

                if (!(p.getPrice() == null)) {
                    listProduct.setPrice(p.getPrice());
                }

                if (!(p.getUpc().equals(""))) {
                    listProduct.setUpc(p.getUpc());
                }

                if (!(p.getStock() == null)) {
                    listProduct.setStock(p.getStock());
                }
                Collections.sort(list);
                CollectionFileStorageUtility.save(list, Product.class); //saves updated list.
                break;
            }
        }
        if (containsProductAlready = false) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, no product was found with that UPC.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * The removeProduct method creates a list of Products using the
     * getProductList method. It then searches the list looking for a Product
     * with a UPC matching the one which was passed in. If found, it removes the
     * item from the list and saves the updated list using the
     * CollectionFileStorageUtility.save method.
     *
     * @param upc The upc to search for.
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */
    public void removeProduct(String upc) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        List<Product> list = getProductList();
        boolean containsProductAlready = false;
        for (Product listProduct : list) {
            if ((listProduct.getUpc().equals(upc))) {
                containsProductAlready = true;
                list.remove(listProduct);//removes the matching object
                Collections.sort(list);
                CollectionFileStorageUtility.save(list, Product.class); //saves updated list.
                System.out.println("Product was removed successfully.");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!containsProductAlready) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, no product was found with that UPC.");
        }
    }
}
```

The Product Class, per request:

```
    /*****************************************************
* Class Product
* @author: Daniel Smith
* @version 1.0.0
* Date: 2/20/2016
* This product contains the class template to create
* products to be stored. It holds thier UPC, long and
* short descriptions, price and amount in stock. 
* The class provides mutators and accessors to modify 
* existing Products.
******************************************************/
package Smithd81;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

/**
 *
 * @author Barad-Dur
 */
public class Product implements Comparable<Product>, Serializable {

    private String upc;
    private String shortDetails;
    private String longDetails;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private Integer stock;

    /**
     * @return the upc
     */
    public String getUpc() {
        return upc;
    }

    /**
     * @param upc the upc to set
     */
    public void setUpc(String upc) {
        this.upc = upc;
    }

    /**
     * @return the shortDetails
     */
    public String getShortDetails() {
        return shortDetails;
    }

    /**
     * @param shortDetails the shortDetails to set
     */
    public void setShortDetails(String shortDetails) {
        this.shortDetails = shortDetails;
    }

    /**
     * @return the longDetails
     */
    public String getLongDetails() {
        return longDetails;
    }

    /**
     * @param longDetails the longDetails to set
     */
    public void setLongDetails(String longDetails) {
        this.longDetails = longDetails;
    }

    /**
     * @return the price
     */
    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    /**
     * @param price the price to set
     */
    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    /**
     * @return the stock
     */
    public Integer getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    /**
     * @param stock the stock to set
     */
    public void setStock(Integer stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Product p) {
        int comparison = this.getUpc().compareTo(p.getUpc());
        return comparison;
    }

}
```

Comment: I edited your question to remove the paste bin link and placed the code in the question instead. For the sake of preserving the question for the future StackOverflow does not encourage the use of external links to code. Just a FYI for the future :)

Comment: Are the fields in your bean, upc, shortDetails, and so forth  ?  If yes, then instead of using ${p.getUpc()}   you could try using  ${p.upc} I just edited that.

Comment: no, and thats likely the problem. the items="${productManager.productList} line returns a List object, which is full of serialized Product objects. The fields upc,  price and so on belong to the Product class. Do I need to also use that in a bean? How would that work?

Comment: @ug_ thank you for the tip.

Comment: I assumed that p was a Product object and that ${productManager.productList} returned a list of Product objects. Is that correct?

Comment: Did you try using ${p.upc} ?

Comment: If you are still having trouble, then you should post your bean code.

Comment: @rickz I did try that for all params, to no avail. I added the bean code to the bottom of the question. Should I also add the Product class?

Comment: I still can't find problem. I guess you should post Product code. Also what does ${p} print out within foreach loop?

Comment: I have added the product class. ${p} does not print anything. I also used a JSTL function to get the length of  p, thinking it would give me 1; it gave me 0.

Comment: I still don't know. Let me think

Comment: The only thing I can think of doing is to put dummy products in the list instead of getting them from CollectionFileStorageUtility.  I would create some Product objects within the getProductList method and add them to productsList and return it.  For example,   Product pd1 = new Product();  pd1.setUpc("test");  productsList.add(pd1); and so forth.

Comment: Interesting idea, I can see what comes of it.

Comment: Another debugging idea is to try printing your data from a scriptlet(forget about JSTL for a moment). Something like  <% for(Product p: productManager.getProductList()){ out.print("upc is " + p.getUpc()); } %>

Comment: interesting. When I paste that in, it says incompatible types. object cannot be converted to Product. Let me look at that code one more time

Comment: Well, I tried some funny stuff. I have changed the code to getProductList, which I will edit in the original post. It now shows the values in the scriptlet but still not in the c:foreach

Comment: My final idea and I know it is a lot of work. If you still can't the JSTL to work, then you might have to redesign your InventoryManager class to conform to JavaBean conventions. Look at https://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-java/javabeans/properties/indexed.html   Treat your list of products as a indexed property( see lines field in MyBean code in linked page). Create a property that is the list and call setProductList in a constructor.

Comment: Please forget my last idea. That redesign is not necessary. I will post my test code.

Comment: Open JSP page in browser. Rightclick and *View Source*. Do you still see unparsed `<c:xxx>` tags there?

Comment: BalusC might be right. You neglected to include the taglib directive in your JSP.  I am sorry I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my test code.

```
package test;
public class Product {
    private String upc;
    public String getUpc() {
        return upc;
    }
    public void setUpc(String upc) {
        this.upc = upc;
    }
}

package test;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class InventoryManager {
    public List<Product> getProductList(){
        ArrayList productList = new ArrayList();
        Product p1 = new Product();
        p1.setUpc("one");
        productList.add(p1);
        Product p2 = new Product();
        p2.setUpc("two");
        productList.add(p2);
        Product p3 = new Product();
        p3.setUpc("three");
        productList.add(p3);
        return productList;
    }
}
```

and my test JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<jsp:useBean id = "productManager" scope = "session"  class = "test.InventoryManager" />
testing   
<c:forEach var="p" items="${productManager.productList}">
    ${p.upc}
</c:forEach>
```

my test works fine and prints

testing one two three

Comment: Your code worked great but did not solve my issue, looks like I have to rewrite from the top..